# netbeans c++ with mysql windows

Tags: c++, mysql, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans 7 (c++) to connect to mySQL using Boost libraries (boost_1_53_0) and the required mySql C++ libraries (include and Lib)
I added the path of the libraries in the project properties->C++ Compiler->include directories.

I also added the path of the libraries in project  properties->linker->include directories.
Finally I added the mysqlcppconn.dll to project  properties->linker->libraries

this is the program: I'm just testing

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/connection.h"
/*
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    sql::Driver *driver ;
    sql ::Connection *conn;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    conn = driver->connect("localhost","root","1qaz");
    return 0;
}
```

I've got this error at the output:
/cygdrive/c/Users/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3/dist/Debug/Cy
gwin-Windows/cppapplication_3.exe: error while loading shared libraries: mysqlcp
pconn.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried some of the suggested solutions about icluding the libraries but it still nothing
any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should put mysqlcppconn.dll into the directory of your executable. Maybe it will require some other DLLs.

This has nothing to do with compiler settings (it looks as if your program compiles ok). The program just cannot locate the DLL when it starts.

Comment: I put the file everywhere and it's still the same

Comment: Have you also put libmysql.dll into the exe's folder?

Comment: I've got this on the output screen: /cygdrive/C/Program Files/NetBeans 7.3/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33
:  4492 Segmentation fault      sh "${SHFILE}"

Comment: I'd recommend to check for errors after the library calls (probably the first returns NULL). Or it would be better to debug this with an IDE's debugger. But that's quite a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I hope it will help someone or reduce time to start with C++ and MySQL development on Windows via NetBeans IDE :)

I'm using

1. NetBeans (8.0.2) IDE
2. MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.22, for Win32
   (x86))
3. g++.exe ((GCC) 4.8.1)

and connection to mysql from C++ code works for me.

Please contact me directly if you need further help.

**1. I needed following header files:**

> ```
> #include <winsock.h>
> #include <mysql.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> ```

**2. Following INCLUDES for g++ compiler:**

> ../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.5/include
>
> ../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include

**3. Following LIBRARIES for g++ linker:**

> ../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.dll

**4. Copy of library (libmysql.dll) for runtime in the same directory where executable is located:**

> ../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.dll